# Benchmark Vue.js components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want to benchmark my vuejs components and have a report with each component individually.
I can't find any plugin to do so, is it ok to just take time inside 'the beforeCreate' and 'mounted' hook ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to benchmark? The initial render time? Components can do lots of things in different situations.

Comment: I want to know how many time my server spend to render each component from the moment the component is called until his ready to be spend to the user. (fetch data + render)